# glassfish jersey FormDataContentDisposition getSize returning -1

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey, multipartform-data

I Have a Jersey RESTful webservice under Glassfish which accepts incoming POST requests for uploading images, consuming `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` which maps to mime type multipart.

When I receive the instance of `FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail` in my service and call `fileDetail.getSize()`

I always get -1

I wonder how is the appropriate way to fetch the correct file size using Jersey and Multipart file upload.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and I'm now seeking for RCA and solutions.

Just a workaround: save the file temporarily and use File#length() method  to get the real size of uploaded file.

More update:

As complement of the above method, keep monitoring saved bytes' size, throw an exception (or do what the policy requires) when the file size threshold is reached.

What's more, don't trust the size given directly by client, which could be faked, unless the client is trusted.

Comment: I can't save it temporarily since I want to validate if it's below a certain size prior to saving it anywhere.

Comment: If so, you don't have to wait until file is completely saved. Size checking could be done during saving. What you've got is an InputStream, from which you could use a buffer to transfer data into a local file, meanwhile, accumulate and count the transfered size. Once the size exceeded the upper limitation, cancel transferring and throw exception or do whatever is needed. If the size is qualified, then the file could be successfully saved.

Comment: That's an alternative but I'd rather do that as a last option since it would waste more processing time just to keep accepting bytes and figure out a file is larger than the limit later on. I'd rather cancel the upload right away if I can get the file metadata correctly containing file size info.

Comment: I understand your pursuit of performance, but if this metadata is provided by client, not calculated by server side codes, then how do you guarantee this metadata is faked? This meta data could help fail fast if the size is bigger. But you should never give up monitoring saving the file, or limit the file size in some other place (like nginx layer etc.).